# Parallel.Foreach Access Violation Issue

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, arrays, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to read blob from database(oracle) and save files onto the system. As the blob size can be huge, i'm appending the bytes. Here scannedLettersDictionary is of type ConcurrentDictionary.

```
ConcurrentQueue<Exception> exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();
Parallel.ForEach(scannedLettersDictionary.Where(y => y.Value.ScannedLetterContent != null).Select(x => x), file =>
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(ScannedLettersDirectory + file.Value.LetterId + ".tiff", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[65536];
            int numBytesToRead = (int)file.Value.ScannedLetterContent.Length;
            int bytesRead = 1;

            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
            {
                while (numBytesToRead > 0 && bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    bytesRead = file.Value.ScannedLetterContent.Read(bytes, 0, Math.Min(numBytesToRead, bytes.Length));
                    writer.Write(bytes);
                    numBytesToRead -= bytesRead;
                }

                writer.Flush();
                writer.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (AggregateException ag) { exceptions.Enqueue(ag); }
    catch (Exception e) { exceptions.Enqueue(e); }
});

if (exceptions.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var exp in exceptions)
    {
        LogError(exp, 66, exp.Message, _letterId);
    }
}
```

Issue is with this line. It gives me Access Violation exception.

```
 bytesRead = file.Value.ScannedLetterContent.Read(bytes, 0, Math.Min(numBytesToRead, bytes.Length));
```

How to make byte[] thread safe inside Parallel.ForEach. I don't want to put lock object outside it as it will not serve me any purpose and will be equivalent to for loop(performance wise).

Appreciate any help.

Comment: how do you ensure that the only one thread can append bytes withou lock statement?

Comment: So is lock the only way out?

Comment: Unless you've got duplicates in your collection, I highly doubt this error is to do with threading. `file.Value.ScannedLetterContent.Read(bytes, 0` is *always* overwriting the first byte in `bytes`. Then you're writing the byte again to `bytes`. I doubt that's causing the error, but it's definitely wrong. In any case, as I said, unless you have `file` duplicated in the collection, or two `file`s with the same `LetterID`, it's very unlikely to do with threads.

Comment: There are not duplicates in CourrentDictionary. The code works fine in forloop.

Comment: Anyway, you should be able to replace all that code with simply `file.Value.ScannedLetterContent.CopyTo(stream);`

Comment: @bayyinah Are you absolutely sure there are no duplicates? If items are using the same stream via `ScannedLetterContent` or the same `LetterId`, then you may get this exception. However, the code itself is not sharing any variables across threads.

Comment: Yes absolutely, no duplicates. Just to add.. I'm using Telerik Data Access. ScannedLetterContent is of type BinaryStream in Model

Comment: You're doing IO work, there's actually no need for `Parallel.ForEach` or any threads. You can do this with async IO.

Comment: @bayyinah there are locking constructs such as Mutex, SpinLock, but it preferable to lock statement for performance gain.